# Process command java.exe finished with non-zero exit value 2

Tags: android, cocos2d-x, android-gradle-plugin

I am new in Android Studio developer, I'm learning Cocos2d-x on window 7 (64bit), I created a project

Cocos2d-x. When I import this project into Android Studio 1.1.0, and run it in Android Studio, I got error.
I was also searching answers from the same error, but they are not suitable for me. Hope everyone help me, thank you very much

here is my error.

```css
Information:Gradle tasks [:testCocos:assembleDebug]
WARNING [Project: :testCocos] Current NDK support is deprecated.  Alternative will be provided in the future.
:testCocos:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:testCocos:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:testCocos:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:libcocos2dx:compileLint
:libcocos2dx:copyReleaseLint UP-TO-DATE
:libcocos2dx:mergeReleaseProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
.........................
:libcocos2dx:packageReleaseJniLibs UP-TO-DATE
:libcocos2dx:packageReleaseLocalJar UP-TO-DATE
:libcocos2dx:packageReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:libcocos2dx:bundleRelease UP-TO-DATE
:testCocos:checkDebugManifest
:testCocos:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:testCocos:prepareProjAndroidLibcocos2dxUnspecifiedLibrary UP-TO-DATE
......................................
:testCocos:preDexDebug UP-TO-DATE
:testCocos:dexDebug
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lorg/cocos2dx/lib/Cocos2dxAccelerometer;
 at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:596)
 at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:554)
 at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:535)
 at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)
 at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
 at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:454)
 at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:303)
 at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
 at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
 at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
Error:Execution failed for task ':testCocos:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'D:\ProgramFiles\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
```

here is my gradle file:

```css
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.sm5tudio.testCocos"
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 21
        ndk {
            moduleName "cocos2dcpp_shared"
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
    sourceSets.main
            {
                jni.srcDirs = []
            }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':libcocos2dx')

}
```

here is manifest:

```css
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.sm5tudio.testCocos"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0"
      android:installLocation="auto">

    <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" />

    <application android:label="@string/app_name"
                 android:icon="@drawable/icon">
      
        <!-- Tell Cocos2dxActivity the name of our .so -->
        <meta-data android:name="android.app.lib_name"
               android:value="cocos2dcpp" />

        <activity android:name="org.cocos2dx.cpp.AppActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name"
                  android:screenOrientation="landscape"
                  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
                  android:configChanges="orientation">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true"
                      android:smallScreens="true"
                      android:normalScreens="true"
                      android:largeScreens="true"
                      android:xlargeScreens="true"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
</manifest>
```

Sorry, i need 10 repulation to post image
This is the dependencies of my library libcocos2dx and testCocos

```html
Cocos2dxlib
AndroidManifest.xml
lib
Cocos2dxAccelerometer
Cocos2dxActivity
Cocos2dxBitmap
Cocos2dxEditBoxDialog
Cocos2dxEditText
Cocos2dxGLSurfaceView
Cocos2dxHandler
Cocos2dxHelper
Cocos2dxLocalStorage
Cocos2dxLuaJavaBridge
Cocos2dxMusic
Cocos2dxRenderer
Cocos2dxSound
Cocos2dxTextInputWraper
Cocos2dxTypefaces
Cocos2dxVideoHelper
Cocos2dxVideoView
Cocos2dxWebView
Cocos2dxWebViewHelper
GameControllerAdapter
GameControllerDelegate
GameControllerUtils

testCocos
AndroidManifest.xml
cocos2dx
cpp
AppActivity
lib
build.gradle
build.gradle
build.gradle
settings.gradle
local.properties
```

Comment: You didn't "run" your code, rather the error occurred while running one of the steps of compiling it - apparently because a class is included twice due to faulty project setup.

Comment: I had inadvertently created "Run code snippet" in my question!
@ Chris Stratton: Plz help me how to fix my error?

Comment: Where do you use org/cocos2dx/lib/Cocos2dxAccelerometer ? Publish the dependencies of your library libcocos2dx

Comment: i just post library libcocos2dx